# [ROS2 Foxy]RVIZ crashes when using Nav2- Turtlebot3

Tags: ros2, rviz

I am currently working on my masters degree project

- I am using Turtlebot3(Raspberry pi 3B+ version) and I am using ROS2 Foxy on a **ubuntu Dualboot**
- I use this command on my ubuntu to launch the navigation2: ros2 launch turtlebot3_navigation2 navigation2.launch.py map:=/path/to/map
  This is the default launch file and I haven't made any changes to it.
- I am facing the following errors when I run the navigation2 with RVIZ.
  These errors seems to occur randomly.

  - InternalErrorException: Cannot create GL vertex buffer in GLHardwareVertexBuffer::GLHardwareVertexBuffer at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rviz-ogre-vendor-8.2.6/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre-v1.12.1-prefix/src/ogre-v1.12.1/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLHardwareVertexBuffer.cpp (line 46)
  - `(min.x <= max.x && min.y <= max.y && min.z <= max.z) && "The minimum corner of the box must be less than or equal to maximum corner"' failed. Aborted

  I also got the same errors when using my **ubuntu VM**

I am new to ROS, can anyone suggest a solution for this? If anyone knows please let me know.

I greatly appreciate any help in this regard,

Thanks in advance

[EDIT] - link to the same question on ROS answers https://answers.ros.org/question/402195/ros2-foxyrviz-crashes-when-using-nav2-turtlebot3/

Answer (score 1):

RViz is having trouble creating the necessary GL context. You can find this issue listed in the [rviz/Troubleshooting](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting)

> This is caused by a lack of the GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object OpenGL
> extension. I have seen two causes for this apparent lack:
>
> ```
> Running rviz remotely (which is not supported)
> Version mismatch between libGL.so and the OpenGL driver.
> ```

To me this suggests that you might need to make sure that you have your graphics drivers setup correctly. Both in your native installation or in your VM with access to the native graphics driver outside the VM such that you have access to the necessary GL resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up upgrading from ROS foxy to Galactic. That seemed to make my errors go away for now.